# LuaTeX 0.85 \pdf* primitive changes and format file generation

Tags: luatex, texlive, format-files, initex

TeX Live 2015 ships with LuaTeX 0.80. As LuaTeX 0.85 became available last month and I am supposed to do be doing other things I found this to be a wonderful opportunity to procrastinate by giving the 0.85 version a try.

Building the executable was unproblematic. However to avoid a

```
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

error, the format files had to be regenerated.

```
fmtutils-sys --all
```

however failed to regenrate the LuaTeX related format files. Doing it manually via:

```
luatex -ini   -jobname=luatex -progname=luaex luatex.ini
```

revealed that the very first line fails:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \pdfoutput
            =1
? 
! Emergency stop.
```

Which is quite bad, because `\pdfoutput` is primitive control sequence of pdfTeX, it is always there, out of the box. But not any more in LuaTeX 0.85 it seems. In fact section 8.1.7 of the LuaTeX manual explains that all but three of the `\pdf*` primitives are gone.

In the same section the manual provides a list of commands to get the traditional pdfTeX `\pdf*`-primitives back. However the use of `\protected` is only possible if the eTeX primitives in LuaTeX have been enabled. That happens in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/config/luatexiniconfig.tex
```

which is the first thing that

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/plain/config/luatex.ini
```

loads. Extending `luatexiniconfig.tex` with list of commands almost succeeds.
The last commands on the list use `\newdimen` which is not a primitive. It is defined in the plain-TeX-Format.

As `luatex.ini` loads `pdfetex.ini` which in turn loads `etex.src` which loads `plain.src` the `\newdimen` command sequence will not be available until after all the files have been processed. However `pdfetex.ini` of course ends with `\dump` end `\endinput` Adding something after `pdfetex.ini` has been processed would be pointless.

Thus, my modified `luatex.ini` therefore looks like this:

```
% $Id: luatex.ini 26647 2012-05-24 23:54:05Z karl $
% Karl Berry, originally written 2008. Public domain.
% PDF output by default.

% must be done first (activation of primitives)
\input luatexiniconfig.tex
\input luatex-unicode-letters.tex
\input pdftexconfig.tex
\input etex.src
\input pdftexmagfix.tex
\newdimen\pdfeachlineheight
\newdimen\pdfeachlinedepth
\newdimen\pdflastlinedepth
\newdimen\pdffirstlineheight
\newdimen\pdfignoreddimen
\dump
\endinput
```

Now `fmtutils-sys` successfully generats the `luatex.fmt` format file.
The `lualatex.fmt` still fails.

The `lualatex.ini` can be extended with the list of `\pdf*` commands just as well. However do something like

```
\protected\def\pdfliteral{\pdfextension literal}
```

one needs at least

```
\catcode`\{=1
\catcode`\}=2
```

as we are in iniTeX-mode. But there very first thing that `latex.ltx` checks is

```
\ifnum\catcode`\{=1
  \errmessage
  {LaTeX must be made using an initex with no format preloaded}
\fi
```

and this is triggered now. Thus the `lualatex.ini` needs and additional

```
\catcode`\{=2
```

It now looks like this:

```
% $Id: lualatex.ini 38624 2015-10-12 23:38:27Z karl $
% Originally written 2008 by Karl Berry. Public domain.

\begingroup
  \catcode`\{=1 %
  \catcode`\}=2 %
% JAW: Enable 'extra' pdfTeX primitives only in .ini file
% latex.ltx enables the extra primitives bu a subset of those from
% pdfTeX are needed to do the configuration below (pdftexconfig.tex).
% Rather than list them all, just enable those classed as 'pdftex'.
    \directlua{tex.enableprimitives('',tex.extraprimitives('pdftex', 'luatex', 'etex'))}
% JAW: Set up job name quoting before latex.ltx
% Web2c pdfTeX/XeTeX quote job names containing spaces, but LuaTeX does
% not do this at the engine level. The behaviour can be changed using
% a callback. Originally this code was loaded via lualatexquotejobname.tex
% but that required a hack around latex.ltx: the behaviour has been altered
% to allow the callback route to be used directly.
  \global\everyjob{\directlua{require("lualatexquotejobname.lua")}}
\endgroup

\catcode`\{=1
\catcode`\}=2

% recreate the traditional pdfTeX primitives here REMOVED FOR BREVITY

\catcode`\{=2

% settings inherited from pdftex
\input pdftexconfig.tex
% pdf output by default

\input latex.ltx
```

Again `latex.ltx` ends with `\dump` and `\endinput` so the necessary `\newdimen` commands:

```
\newdimen\pdfeachlineheight
\newdimen\pdfeachlinedepth
\newdimen\pdflastlinedepth
\newdimen\pdffirstlineheight
\newdimen\pdfignoreddimen
```

cannot be inserted after the `\input latex.ltx` line, that would be to late.
Removing the last to lines from `latex.ltx`

```
\dump
\endinput
```

and placing them in `lualatex.ini` as follows

```
% settings inherited from pdftex
\input pdftexconfig.tex
% pdf output by default

\input latex.ltx

\newdimen\pdfeachlineheight
\newdimen\pdfeachlinedepth
\newdimen\pdflastlinedepth
\newdimen\pdffirstlineheight
\newdimen\pdfignoreddimen

\dump
\endinput
```

allows `fmtutil-sys --all` to regenerate the `lualatex.fmt` format file. But now that the LaTeX source has been changed all other formats of course are broken.

There must be a better way to do this! Any ideas?

Comment: 'Wait for TL'16' :-) The LaTeX team, TeX Live maintainers, Christian Schenk and others are working on various issues to do with LuaTeX v0.85 and some related matters. We _are_ on it but need a bit longer to get it all going. (Indeed, I think I've found quite a problematic issue in LuaTeX v0.85 for getting a 'nice' common set up _in the last hour_.)

Comment: As far as I know, the LaTeX team is actively working on making LuaTeX 0.85 usable with no hassle. The changes have been too many for hoping the previous setup still works.

Comment: @Uli BTW, if you are _really_ interested I can add you onto my CC list for the work going on here!

Comment: @JosephWright yes please, support my procrastination even further ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LuaTeX from v0.85 onward removes essentially all of the pdfTeX 'back end' primitives in favour of three new interfaces:

- `\pdfextension`
- `\pdffeedback`
- `\pdfvariable`

At the same time, there are several other renames and changes to the Lua side (the original `token` library is removed, and the `newtoken` library replaces it meaning there is no `newtoken` any more). These changes require significant work in the format-building process (many of the primitives impacted are not used by end users), in parts of the LaTeX kernel (where the change to the `token` library impacts) and in packages (most obviously graphics drivers and `ifpdf`).

'Fixing' all of this in a transparent way is non-trivial. (There's not just LaTeX to think about: plain LuaTeX is also affected.) The LaTeX team have been working on this with the TeX Live maintainer for some time, deciding on how best to handle the required adaptation. At the time of writing, we have several parts of the 'jigsaw' decided but are still implementing them. There are particular issues with the package support: it's very likely that a 'compatibility' package will be needed at least in the short term. (The core team do not control all packages using the PDF back end primitives!) There is also a need to co-ordinate with MiKTeX, TeX Live management utilities and so on.

All of this means that official (CTAN release) support for LuaTeX v0.85+ will not happen 'just yet'. Currently the plan is to get this in place by early in 2016 with a definite requirement for it all to work for TL'16. Anyone testing in the meantime should get in contact with the team/me to get onto the CC list for discussions.

To be clear: unless you are *entirely comfortable* hand-rebuilding formats and messing with your TeX tree, *do not try LuaTeX v0.85 but wait for official support from TeX Live*.